# Godaddy Ubuntu 3.6 mod_rewrite issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have been at this for 3 hours and cannot seem to get `mod_rewrite` to work with GoDaddy on a shared server under a subdomain.  I have an app in a subdirectory and I've used the same rules before on multiple servers so I know they work.  Here's what I've got:

PHP Version 5.3.10-1 Ubuntu3.6

```
subdomain root/
-.htaccess
--appdir/
---.htaccess
----public/
-----.htaccess
```

**subdomain root/.htaccess**

```
Options -Multiviews
```

That's it for the document root `.htaccess`, many have suggested to do this with GoDaddy servers.

**appdir/.htaccess**

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /appdir
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

This routes all requests to the `appdir/public` directory

**appdir/public/.htaccess**

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appdir/public ### also tried just adding /appdir ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

Just to be sure `mod_rewrite` was available, I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite` from Bash and checked after restarting apache with `print_r(apache_get_modules());` and sure enough it's there so needless to say I'm at a complete loss as to what the problem may be.  Anyone have similar experiences with GoDaddy and have suggestion on what to do to get `mod_rewrite` running?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say godaddy, but have you tried your .htaccess elsewhere with success?

Comment: Try throwing some invalid text in your htaccess files... chances are your AllowOverride isn't set right on the site root so .htaccess isn't being looked at. if the server is looking at the .htaccess then you should get a 500 error from the server

Comment: @Orangepill - great suggestion, I just riddled all three with invalid text and didn't get an error so I assume you are correct.  Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @Steve, I've tried them on Aplus, Inmotion as well as locally on both windows/ubuntu and have never ran into this prob.  It has to be an issue with the server config.

Comment: in the server config there will be a Directory Directive that points at your web root... Set the `AllowOverride All` is usually all it takes

Comment: you will have to restart apache to make is pick up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a default ubuntu install to get up and running with mod_rewrite you have to :

Enable mod rewrite

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then make sure you are allowing overrides in the site config (/etc/apache2/sites-available/)
and update the line `AllowOverride All` in the '' directive.

reload apache config

```
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it running.